# Binomial series expansion of a trinomial?

Tags: taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients, physics, binomial-theorem, electromagnetism

In electrostatics, the potential of a charge $q$ placed on the $z$-axis at $z=a$ is

\begin{equation}
\phi=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r_1}
\end{equation}

where $r_1$ is the distance from the observation point to the charge.

Using law of cosines we get

\begin{equation}
\phi=\frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0} (r^2+a^2-2ar\text{ }\text{cos}\theta)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}

That will be Eq.(12.2).

Arkfen's Mathematical Methods for Physicist$^1$ states:

> Consider the case of $r > a$ or, more precisely, $r^2 > |a^2 − 2ar\text{ cos θ}|$. The radical in
>   Eq. (12.2) may be expanded in a binomial series and then rearranged in powers of ($a/r$).

The expression is a trinomial: $((\frac{a}{r})^2+1-\frac{2a}{r}\text{cos}\theta)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

How can it be expanded through a binomial series? I can't find any source making this expansion explicitly, instead jumping directly into Legendre polynomials.

[1] George Arkfen and Hans Weber. *Mathematical Methods for Physicist* (6th ed. pp. 742)

Comment: Treat the $1$ and the $(a/r)^2+2(a/r)\cos(\theta)$ as the two terms in the binomial.  You can always expand out the polynomial you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multinomial theorem, for the case $n=3$, says that 
$$(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^n = 
\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3 = n} \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!} x_1^{k_1} x_2^{k_2} x_3^{k_3}
$$
This generalizes to possibly non-integer real exponents $r$ by writing $r! = \Gamma(r+1)$ and 
$$
\sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3 \in \Bbb Z} \frac{r!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!(r-k_1-k_2-k_3)!} x_1^{k_1} x_2^{k_2} x_3^{k_3}
$$

(Notice that in the case of positive integer $r$ this series ends because a $(-1)!$ starts appearing in the denominator, and that is infinite leading to the terms being zero.)

In this case, $(-\frac12)! = \Gamma(\frac12)$ is $\sqrt{\pi}$ and the factors of $\sqrt{\pi}$ will cancel.

For the expression at hand, the lowest order terms in an expansion for $a << r$ are:
$$
\left[ 1+ \frac{2a}{r}\cos\theta + \left(\frac{a}{r} \right)^2  \right]^{-\frac12}=
1 - \frac{a}{2r} + \left( \frac38-\cos\theta\right)\frac{a^2}{r^2} -  
\left( \frac5{16}-\frac32\cos\theta\right)\frac{a^3}{r^3}+ \cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} \sim 1-\frac{1}{2}x, x<<1.$$
So,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(a/r)(a/r+2\cos(\theta))}} \sim 1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{a}{r}(\frac{a}{r}+2\cos(\theta)) = 1-\cos(\theta)\frac{a}{r}-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{a}{r})^2.$$